# Ecoregions shapefiles: subsetting, extracting and summarizing data from raster

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, masking, extract-by-mask

I am attempting to subset and project an ecoregions shapefile from : [EPA ECOREGIONS](http://www.epa.gov/wed/pages/ecoregions/na_eco.htm#Level%20II)
my data set is found here: [SHAPEFILES and RASTER](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/27cft3118dha6xt/AACTbn2S1oZ1DVbiBl4npDlla)
When I run this code, two major problems occur: 1) I cannot get the subset of ecoregions to plot on top of my raster file and 2) I cannot extract the values (summary information) from the subset of ecoregions from the raster. Can anyone help with this?

```
require (raster) raster<-raster('FG_RCP26_2050.tif') 
plot (raster)
```

[image: Raster with Data]

```
ecoregions.all<- readOGR("NA_CEC_Eco_Level2.shp",layer="NA_CEC_Eco_Level2") 
head (ecoregions.all) 
plot (ecoregions.all)
```

[image: ecoregions]

```
#this is the subset of ecoregions that I need 
NA_L2<-c('5.1','5.2','5.3','8.1','8.3','8.4','8.5')

#subset the ecoregion.all to just those in the northeast
#this must be where the problem is 
ne.ecoregions = coregions.all[match(toupper(NA_L2),toupper(ecoregions.all$NA_L2CODE)),]

#plot ne.ecoregions on top of raster and extract summary statistics for each ecoregion 
#summary statistics =distribution of values within each ecoregion
plot (raster) plot (ne.ecoregions, add=T)

ecoregions.raster<-mask (raster, ne.ecoregions) 
summary (ecoregions.raster)
```

Comment: Could you please focus this a bit by defining a question? You might also want to add an `R` tag to get more attention.

Comment: and instead of using `mask`, try using the `extract` command. Works miracles ;)

Comment: Hm, there's a file named 'siteXspecies.csv', but no raster in your Dropbox folder.